# Query for retrieving all answer ids for questions which a user already answered

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-explorer, data-dump, api

I'm looking for a query from a Stack Overflow dump to find this. Example: user-id 'XXXXX' answered_list_id:[10,20,30,40]

Also, I don't consider whether the answer is accepted or not.

```
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Posts AS a
ON u.Id = a.OwnerUserId
INNER JOIN Posts AS q
ON q.Id = a.ParentId
INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt
ON q.Id = pt.PostId
```

This is what I thought about how to join the tables so far.

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. Do you really just need to get answer IDs for the answers belonging to a user (or users)?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1615716?opt.textResults=true&UserId=811) that selects all Posts.Id of the answers (Posts.PostTypeId = 2) for a specific user (the userid is stored in Posts.OwnerUserId).
I've then concat and string_agg the projection so I get the JSON format you seem to be looking for.

The same SQL can be run on the data-dump, assuming you use SQL Server as RDBMS. Other flavors allow you to do the same.

```
select concat('{answered_list_id: [', string_agg(id,  ','), ']}') answered_list_id
from posts
where posttypeid = 2 -- answers
and owneruserid = ##userid?811##
```

This is the result today:
`{answered_list_id: [7875,11815,13193,13365,18994,20712,22854,23208,23733,33339,33826,33857,34651,36356,37052,37518,38102,38229,39931,39988,40012,40024,41186,44762,45211,45971,47508,47554,47874,50274,50581,52805,52892,53048,53485,55149,57214,57332,57827,58031,60136,60671,60688,60735,60778,61123,74610,75015,80036,80098,80159,87462,87498,89179,99337,99787,99873,102903,102941,103398,105086,105828,108790,51169,108955,111545,112136,112269,116998,118188,121708,124359,130551,135324,135586,136816,140373,143889,144188,144856,146209,146770,147068,149480,149859,153607,159053,168397,169768,170731,176793,179710,179717,183048,183645,183737,184964,185140,185283,189558,189570,191454,192205,196138,196211,197823,199526,200034,202004,202713,206566,210077,210393,213311,213776,215599,236655,239186,241751,244507,245073,245316,247057,247261,247392,255102,255269,262260,262318,269561,269688,281727,282271,282328,284323,284638,296460,301067,306225,307385,307509,312975,315983,316019,317688,318406,360868,361454,361594,361724,368893,376173,381593,381652,383503,384754,385518,387869,390625,391844,391963,391982,393149,395364,395855,395864,403709,406174,411395,412033,413602,413851,414229,415072,415264,421333,421436,423187,423342,433731,440387,455533,458953,475203,476601,476616,476861,504097,504777,505043,505564,505622,518069,518894,526369,526536,526575,529753,530685,533852,534458,534716,542060,543820,547500,553986,554984,558542,561689,562636,562781,563084,565799,565948,568249,573851,579029,580280,580303,587097,597008,597293,617413,619844,620624,620955,621545,622934,624036,627137,632213,632816,635254,637214,645324,652387,663575,694914,710996,716134,732022,732910,736728,740499,741182,742438,744224,42978,55585,61118,144847,361601,401129,451733,597070,633066,745542,753071,754625,758989,766017,766121,770338,779708,779933,780178,783506,787514,787891,789689,789768,791200,794372,794948,795599,798744,798899,799856,800885,803339,805406,812255,815127,815564,815608,815674,815939,818218,822442,822486,826806,827312,828178,836892,843799,844706,844902,846425,858707,866829,873607,875202,885196,886085,889171,892931,894715,898140,932657,932748,951841,953381,957140,978463,978660,982215,982971,984132,984178,988017,989297,989556,993318,993355,993391,997395,999001,1003934,1004014,1008947,1010173,1010495,1010701,1013226,1022820,1024774,1099483,1099581,1107023,1122639,1162093,1162655,1183617,1184963,1191435,1203924,1215899,1223775,1236863,1283380,1283643,1332203,1332516,1344492,1348087,1348791,1350579,1350612,1381903,1382264,1384055,1386750,1407398,1413358,1429525,1434952,1493054,1511327,1511378,1511666,1511874,1516951,1557861,1562558,1575512,1578232,1602795,1602859,1627084,1633558,1735351,1811119,1817481,1817583,1820585,1822669,1829636,1877007,1891771,1941576,1944483,1956720,1967708,1970825,1971742,1971799,1972804,2001076,2022790,2079520,2090146,2096023,2098042,2105652,2125784,2128324,2142804,2144120,2153526,2159488,2172493,2201789,2214115,2217464,2234685,2235868,2263454,2268067,2270801,2275718,2278317,2313991,2343615,2399226,2413364,2504867,2541959,2671068,2730961,2768552,3087573,3087910,3114704,3119508,3120968,3122226,3122295,3122624,3136155,3159642,3206145,3209555,3284834,3359412,3385371,3390502,3391157,3392460,3450938,3452640,3552251,3580957,3589035,3686207,3724758,3729691,3738298,3973820,4046492,4248890,4571495,4601056,4621061,4838684,5188097,5355860,5766065,5837975,5862862,6442474,8022631,20860676,20865630,21066493,23349429,23623131,23749463,38929858,62919739]}`

I'm happy I didn't take Jon Skeet as an example.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the wonderful [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).